# Portfolio Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multi-select, portfolio

I'm using wordpress as a website CMS. I just use pages, and not the posts.
I'm looking for a wordpress portfolio that allows me the following thing :

I would like to filter portfolio with multiple terms,
For example :

Colors (Category)
- Red  (Choice
- Blue
- Black

Topic
- Car
- Bus
- Truck

making 2 choices, the plugin will display only 'Red' 'Cars"

One good example  for me :
http://www.ldlc.com/image-son/television/support-mural/c4399/
Here the closest plugin I've found :
http://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-filterable-portfolio/developers/
This one works perfectly, but I can't cross 2 or more terms to reduce results like a funnel.

Option : I can use the posts instead of simples images if it is easier to parse, with a good looking display ...

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use custom post type and taxonomy to manage your requirement.

There are some plugin which works similar to your requirement.

[Nimble Portfolio](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nimble-portfolio/) plugin have this features. See its demo [here](http://www.nimble3.com/portfolio-demo/)

Comment: ok, I'll create custom post type and test it; Nimble Portfolio is not yet ready for a multi term search, probably soon